# How to optimize the jQuery html table creation code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to add the table dynamically based on the data comparison report within the div. Below the code to achieve the same.

**jQuery Code**

```
$('#tblComparisonReportContent').append('<table border="1" width=\"50%\"><tr><td colspan="5" align="center">Project1</td></tr><tr><td colspan="3">Feb 12,2017 - Feb 18, 2017</td>" and so on
```

**HTML Table Code**

This is the template and each TR -> TD is dynamic

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <table border="1" width="50%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" align="center">Project 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">Feb 12,2017 - Feb 18, 2017</td>
                <td colspan="2">Feb 12,2017 - Feb 18, 2017</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>PASSED</td>
                <td>FAILED</td>
                <td>PASSED</td>
                <td>FAILED</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Env1</td>
                <td>83%</td>
                <td>17%</td>
                <td>88%</td>
                <td>12</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Env2</td>
                <td>83%</td>
                <td>17%</td>
                <td>88%</td>
                <td>12</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Env3</td>
                <td>83%</td>
                <td>17%</td>
                <td>88%</td>
                <td>12</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Env4</td>
                <td>83%</td>
                <td>17%</td>
                <td>88%</td>
                <td>12</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Env5</td>
                <td>83%</td>
                <td>17%</td>
                <td>88%</td>
                <td>12</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Solution Assitance Needed:**

I am able to add the table inside the div with dynamic values. However, this code looks ugly and does not seems to be an optimized. I am new to jQuery. Requesting experts to suggest ideas (from jQuery point of view) enhance this, instead of passing the entire HTML into append.

Comment: how about using loops in your `<tr>` and `<td>`? initially create `<table>` then add `id`. then you can append your table with `<tr> <td>` using a loop.

Comment: Thanks. I will give a try

Answer (score 0):

Just yopu can pass json array and generate the table. I assume you know how to pass response as json.

### HTML

```
<table border="1" width="50%" id="tblComparisonReportContent">
  <thead>
    <tr><td colspan="5">Project</td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

### php back end

```
$arrayTbl = array(''=>)
// you can create an array of values
$arrayjson = array('success' => true,'rows'=>array('projectname'=>'abc') );        
echo json_encode($arrayjson);
```

### Jquery end

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 data = {
   action: 'your_action',
 };

 jQuery.post( ajaxurl, data, function( response ) {
   response = JSON.parse(response);

   if(response.success) {
     var table = $("#tblComparisonReportContent tbody");

     $(response.row).each(function(val) {
       var tr = "<tr>";
       tr += "<td colspan=5>"+val.projectname+"</td>";
       tr += "</tr>";
       table.append(tr);
     });
   }
 });
 </script>
```

try to get idea from this, I didn't test the code, I suppose I have an idea about json  just loop your json response and build your table inside the each function.